# ways to test mass mobile push notifications

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, windows-phone

We have a system that is responsible for pushing mobile notification for iOS, Android and Windows phones. We have few accounts for each platform (as we have few applications). So far we have been able to test that portion of our system with a handful number of devices, thus handful number of messages but we need to be able to test our service with mass numbers. So for instance, our system does the same with email, so we use Google's "+" feature to test that we are able to send tens of thousands of emails in few minutes, but how can we do this with mobile push?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

For Google Cloud Messaging, you can use the `dry_run` parameter, which allows you to send many requests to the GCM server without actaully sending messages to the devices :

> **dry_run**    If included, allows developers to test their request without actually sending a message. Optional. The default value is false, and must be a JSON boolean.

As far as I know Apple Push Notifications don't have a similar mechanism. You can write a process that simulates the APNs server. It would have to accept incoming client sockets, and be able to read the notification binary data sent by the clients (possibly verifying the correctness of the incoming data).

You can do something similar with Microsift Push Notifications.